# How to prevent google from indexing <script type="application/json"> content

Tags: javascript, json, web-crawler

I have discovered through Google's webmaster tools that google is crawling paths that look like links embedded in json in a `<script type="application/json">` tag.  This json is later parsed and used on the client side.

The problem is that the json contains paths that are not valid links, and Google is treating them as links, and so it is trying to crawl them and getting a steadily increasing amount of 404s, and thus increasing unnecessary crawler traffic.

What can I do to prevent google from attempting to crawl these paths?  I can add some patterns to robots.txt, but I want to ensure that google is ignoring the contents of the script tag entirely, and not trying to parse it for paths that look like links.

Comment: Have you edited/created a [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) file to tell the bots to ignore those paths?

Comment: Are they in your [robots.txt](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt) file?

Comment: @PatrickEvans and zero298, see my third paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

Try this markup:

```
<!--googleoff: all-->
<script type="application/json">
  // your json content here
</script>
<!--googleon: all>
```

As written in [this](https://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/) post.

Plus few more articles:
[Preparing for a Crawl](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/preparing.html)
[FAQ - How do i use the googleon/googleoff Tags?](https://novascotia.ca/search/faq/faq_011.asp)

**PS:**

For even more secure way: when possible,
try to use content, generated "on-fly" such as ajax loading.

Comment: Thank you!  I had just come across the same thing and will be trying that.

Comment: It appears that this is only supported by the Google Search Appliance which is a private search product.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19489890/610585.  I'll still try it out to see if it happens to work, since the documentation linked in that answer does not _explicitly_ state that it won't work for a normal Google search, but I don't expect it to work.  I'll report back what I find.

Comment: Thanks, @undefined! it's a very interesting experiment thing. Also I suggest you to append the script with ajax if possible

Comment: The json is included in the initial response as a performance optimization to avoid having to wait for an XHR request before the first content is displayed.

Comment: @undefined, having the same issue. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @undefined did you ever figure out a solution to this?